# Databind WPF TreeView With Mixed Types and Categorized Sub-TreeViewItems

Tags: wpf, xaml, treeview

I'm trying to build a TreeView in WPF that has categories.

Basically the structure looks like this:

```
Root  
 |_
 | Cat A
 |_
 | Cat B
 |_
   Cat C
```

Each Category is bound to a separate observable collection.  Most of my categories are very simple.  The TreeViewItem that is the category has it's ItemsSource set and there is no hierarchy.  However, I do have a category which needs to be represented in a special hierarchy.

Image that "Cat C" in the above tree then becomes like this:

```
Servers
  |_
  | [SERVER A's DISPLAY NAME]
  |  |_
  |  | Namespaces
  |  |  |_
  |  |_   [NAMESPACE alpha's DISPLAY NAME]
  |  | Deployments
  |  |  |_
  |  |_   [DEPLOYMENT 1's DISPLAY NAME]
  |_   Configuration File
    [SERVER B's DISPLAY NAME]
```

Basically, what I want is the hard coded parent TreeViewItem to have a static header.  That item should then have a collection of items with their names shown.  For each child of the original parent there should be three static items which have a dynamic list of children.

Writing this out makes me think that this should be a very simplistic problem to solve.  However, after playing with the XAML for a couple of days I cannot get a hierarchy to work.  Below is the farthest I've been able to get.  I've used a composite collection called Children to get the Namespaces, Deployments, and the Configuration File into one collection.  However, I cannot separate them out.

```
<TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Configuration.Servers}" 
                      IsExpanded="True" >
            <TreeViewItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TreeViewItem}}">
                    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True"/>
                </Style>
            </TreeViewItem.ItemContainerStyle>

            <TreeViewItem.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Margin="0,2,2,0">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Source="/WPF;component/Images/server_chart.png"
                                   Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Cognos Servers" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TreeViewItem.HeaderTemplate>

            <TreeViewItem.Resources>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemSource="{Binding Path=Children}" DataType="{x:Type local:Server}">
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TreeViewItem}}" >
                            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True"/>
                        </Style>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" PreviewMouseRightButtonDown="OnPreviewMouseRightButtonDown">
                        <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                            <ContextMenu>
                                <MenuItem Header="Refresh" Click="TreeItemMenu_AddNewClient">
                                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                                        <Image Source="/WPF;component/Images/arrow_refresh.png" />
                                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                                </MenuItem>
                                <MenuItem Header="Add Client..." Click="TreeItemMenu_AddNewClient" />
                                <Separator />
                                <MenuItem Header="Remove" Click="TreeItemMenu_RemoveClick">
                                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                                        <Image Source="/WPF;component/Images/server_delete.png" />
                                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                                </MenuItem>
                            </ContextMenu>
                        </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                    </TextBlock>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Clients}" DataType="{x:Type local:Namespace}">
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TreeViewItem}}" >
                            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True"/>
                        </Style>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" PreviewMouseRightButtonDown="OnPreviewMouseRightButtonDown" />
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Client}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}"
                               ContextMenu="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ContextMenuTreeItem}" 
                               PreviewMouseRightButtonDown="OnPreviewMouseRightButtonDown" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </TreeViewItem.Resources>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mike,

Mixing static and model data probably won't get you where you want. You'll have to create an actual ViewModel that contains the static nodes, etc.
I highly recommend [Josh Smith's TreeView ViewModel tutorials](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/TreeViewWithViewModel.aspx). This is the first one, but look around for more info. He is one of the most knowledgeable developer on that subject. We had great success following his recommendations.

Comment: You're answer is correct.  I guess I could say I was half way there.  I resisted creating a ViewModel for the categorized headings.  After I created a generic model to represent a categorized heading it worked out better.  Still not as clean as I like, but it now works.